# Ошибка three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Пытаюсь обернуть в текстуру куб. Когда пытаюсь использовать `EventListener Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` - жалуется, а просто `loader.onload=func...` - ничего не происходит.

```
window.onload = init;
var scene, camera, render;
var cube, cube_geometry, cube_material;
var cube_texture, loader;

function init(){
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
    camera.position.z = 700;

     cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100,100);
     cube_texture = new THREE.Texture(); 
     loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

     /*loader.addEventListener('load',function (event){
        cube_texture.image = event.content;
        cube_texture.needsUpdate = true;
     },false);*/
    loader.load('texture.jpg');
    loader.onload = function(event){
        cube_texture.image = event.content;
        cube_texture.needsUpdate = true;
    }
     cube_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:cube_texture,overdraw:true});
     cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry,cube_material);

     scene.add(cube);

    render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    render.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(render.domElement);

    //animation();
    render.render(scene,camera);
}

function animation(){
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animation);

    render.render(scene,camera);
    }
```

Делаю по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF50PAx3Fio&list=PL1iPwzIyAqwYnHP8999G-PcKp75IDkb5n&index=7).

Comment: @Nirfik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Документация [ImageLoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/ImageLoader)

```
.load ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError )
```

У вас должно быть так:

```
loader.load('texture.jpg', function(event){
    cube_texture.image = event.content;
    cube_texture.needsUpdate = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

loader.load('texture.jpg',
    function ( image ) {
        cube_texture.image = image;
        cube_texture.needsUpdate = true;
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    });
```