# TypeError: textureLoader.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

В консоли выводится TypeError: textureLoader.addEventListener is not a function. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему.

```
window.onload = init;
var scene, camera, render;
var cube_geometry, cubeTexture, textureLoader;
var cube_material, cube;

function init(){
 container = document.createElement('div');
 document.body.appendChild(container);

 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

 camera.position.z = 1000;

 cube_geometry =  new THREE.CubeGeometry(300,300,300, 7, 7, 7);// последние аргументы - кол-во сегментов
 cubeTexture = new THREE.Texture();
 textureLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

 textureLoader.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    cubeTexture.image = event.content;
    cubeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
 });

 textureLoader.load('texturebox.jpg');

 cube_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
 //var cube_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: cubeTexture, overdraw: true});
 cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry,cube_material);

 scene.add(cube);


 render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 container.appendChild(render.domElement);

 animation();

 function animation() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    render.render(scene, camera);
    }
}
```

Comment: нашла решение вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/389159/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-three-js

Comment: `THREE.CubeGeometry()` не используется уже несколько лет, вместо него теперь `THREE.BoxGeometry()`. Похоже, что Вы используете какой-то очень древний пример.

Comment: да, так и есть, спасибо

Comment: да было бы за что ;)

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener()` - это метод класса `EventDispatcher`, но ваш `textureLoader` нет объектом этого класса (или субкласса).

И так вместо

```
 textureLoader.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    cubeTexture.image = event.content;
    cubeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
 });
```

используйте

```
THREE.EventDispatcher.call(textureLoader);
textureLoader.addEventListener('start', function(event) {    
    cubeTexture.image = event.content;
    cubeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    });
textureLoader.dispatchEvent({type:'start'});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но почему-то та же ошибка TypeError: textureLoader.addEventListener is not a function